# Nested UITableViewDataSource doesn't call cellForRowAt:

Tags: swift, uitableview, datasource

I am attempting to have a `UITableView` (Major) which contains another `UITableView` (Minor) in each of its cells. The major and minor table views have their own datasource object classes and the MajorDatasource object contains an array of the MinorDatasource objects as shown below.

I have put breakpoints in the `UITableViewDatasource` functions for each of the classes and it looks like the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function for `MinorDatasource` is never being called, even though the `labels` array contains objects.

I understand that the `datasource` property of a `UITableView` is weak and therefore needs a strong reference to it somewhere, however, I would have thought this would true in this case, is there anything I am doing wrong here?

```
class MajorDatasource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    var minorDatasources:[MinorDatasource]

    init(minorDatasources:[MinorDatasource]) {
        self.minorDatasources = minorDatasources
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return minorDatasources.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MajorTableViewCell")! as! MajorTableViewCell
        cell.tableView.dataSource = minorDatasources[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

class MinorDatasource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    var labels:[String]

    init(labels:[String]) {
        self. labels = labels
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return labels.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MinorTableViewCell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = labels[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: So you mean to say the tableview dataSource methods in 'MinorDatasource' are not getting called?

Comment: @nikBhosale numberOfRowsInSection is being called (and returning, say 2) but cellForRowAt is not being called.

Comment: this should not happen if numberOfRows returning some values as both are data source methods. It would be possible that numberOfRows has called but not cellForRow only when numberOfRows returns '0'

Comment: @nikBhosale This scenario can happen if the datasource is being released for some reason, however, I am not sure why that would be the case in this instance since, the datasource is is the minorDatasources array.

Comment: could it be 'dequeueReusableCell' cell then?

Comment: @nikBhosale dequeueReusableCell is returning a UITableViewCell in MajorDatasource and isn't being called in MinorDatasource, so it appears to be behaving correctly.

Comment: I think the whole design of how you handle the dataSources for those tableViews that are inside of the other tableView cells is a bit odd, if not wrong.
You should pass the ```labels``` array to the cell, and inside the cell class handle the datasource, but not pass around dataSource objects.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the rest of your code - Cell classes, controller classes, etc - so it's tough to say what you might be missing or doing wrong.

So, based on the code you *did* include, and your description, here is a working example that should be pretty close to what you're going for.

Result:

[image]

All via code, so no `@IBOutlets` and such... Just create a new `UIViewController` and assign its class as `MajorMinorViewController`:

```
//
//  MajorMinorViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 9/13/19.
//

import UIKit

class MajorTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var tableView: UITableView = {
        let v = UITableView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        contentView.backgroundColor = .yellow

        contentView.addSubview(tableView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 205.0),
            ])

        tableView.register(MinorTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MinorTableViewCell")

    }
}

class MinorTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    // default UITableViewCell
}

class MajorDatasource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    var minorDatasources:[MinorDatasource]

    init(minorDatasources:[MinorDatasource]) {
        self.minorDatasources = minorDatasources
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return minorDatasources.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MajorTableViewCell")! as! MajorTableViewCell
        cell.tableView.dataSource = minorDatasources[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

class MinorDatasource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    var labels:[String]

    init(labels:[String]) {
        self.labels = labels
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return labels.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MinorTableViewCell") as! MinorTableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = labels[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

class MajorMinorViewController: UIViewController {

    var tableView: UITableView = {
        let v = UITableView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    var minorLabels: [[String]] = [
        ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven"],
        ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"],
        ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
    ]

    var majorDatasource: MajorDatasource!

    var minorDatasources:[MinorDatasource] = [MinorDatasource]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(tableView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])

        for labelArray in minorLabels {
            let mds = MinorDatasource(labels: labelArray)
            minorDatasources.append(mds)
        }

        tableView.register(MajorTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MajorTableViewCell")

        majorDatasource = MajorDatasource(minorDatasources: minorDatasources)

        tableView.dataSource = majorDatasource

    }

}
```